# Index out of range using Flask/Python

Tags: python, flask, sqlite, jinja2

I am working on a web app and running into some issues with the following code. I have a database where I need to update a value. When I try to update the value I am getting an index out of range error, however when I run the code with just python not using the web part it runs and performs as expected.. I cannot figure out what is changing when I try it in part with flask and an HTML form. Here is my code to update the database;

EDIT:: After more testing it seems there is some issue with the form pushing the data I need back to /poplesson. If change these lines;

```
user_id = request.form['clientid']
pck_id = request.form['packageid']
```

to

```
user_id = 1
pck_id = 1
```

it will work as planned, however that is not what I need as I need those ID's to be pulled from the DB.

```
@app.route("/poplesson", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def poplesson():
if request.method == 'GET':
    return render_template('view_packages.html')
elif request.method == 'POST':
    con = sqlite3.connect('utpg.db')
    db = con.cursor()
    user_id = request.form['clientid']
    pck_id = request.form['packageid']
    package = db.execute("SELECT * FROM packages WHERE client_id = ?;", (user_id, ))
    result = package.fetchall()
    privatelessons = result[0][4] ##Without flask this run, with flask this  throws an index error.
    pop = privatelessons - 1
    db.execute("UPDATE packages SET privatelesson = ? WHERE client_id = ? AND pck_id = ?;", (pop, user_id, pck_id, ))
    con.commit()
    return render_template('view_packages.html')
```

This is the code I am using to display the HTML and get the value from the forms..

```
<table>
{% for col in items %}
<tr>
<td>{{ col['pck_id'] }}</td>
<td>{{ col['client_id'] }}</td>
<td>{{ col['date'] }}</td>
<td>{{ col['price'] }}</td>
<td>{{ col['privatelesson'] }}</td>
<td>{{ col['shortgamelesson'] }}</td>
<td>{{ col['playinglesson'] }}</td>
<td>{{ col['notes'] }}</td>
<td><form class="form-container" action="/deletepackage" method="POST">
<input class="form-field"  value="{{ col['pck_id'] }}" name="packageid" />  <br />
    <input class="submit-button" type="submit" value="DELETE Package" />  </form>
 </td>
 <td><form class="form-container" action="/poplesson" method="POST">
 <input class="form-field"  value="{{ col['client_id'] }}" name="clientid" />  <br />
    <input class="form-field"  value="{{ col['pck_id'] }}" name="packageid" />
    <input class="submit-button" type="submit" value="Subtract Private Lesson" /></form></td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
</body>
```

if I do just this part in python, it runs as expected and using a DB viewed I can see the DB is updated. Any thoughts?

```
    con = sqlite3.connect('utpg.db')
    db = con.cursor()
    user_id = request.form['clientid']
    pck_id = request.form['packageid']
    package = db.execute("SELECT * FROM packages WHERE client_id = ?;", (user_id, ))
    result = package.fetchall()
    privatelessons = result[0][4] ##Without flask this run, with flask this  throws an index error.
    pop = privatelessons - 1
    db.execute("UPDATE packages SET privatelesson = ? WHERE client_id = ? AND pck_id = ?;", (pop, user_id, pck_id, ))
    con.commit()
```

Comment: Check that you are using the same database with and without Flask

Comment: What is the posted value of clientid and packageid? Does it work outside flask because you're setting them to 1 instead of '1'?

Comment: It is the same DB as I running locally just testing everything. I just added.. int_user = int(user_id), int_pck = int(pck_id) and that seems to have made it work. But it doesn't make much sense, the other form right above it did not require me to call int on the form input and the function is more of less the same.. Any thoughts on why? Also, my return statement at the end of /poplesson is not rendering the template for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I could think of two possible reasons:

1. Database configuration you are using with/without Flask are different
2. Check the `type` and value of your `user_id` in both the code. It might be different.